# How to get transform scale value based on the current devices width at runtime in JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, adobe-edge

I have an Adobe Edge animation. Through the code it is responsive. But at the start of the website it loads in the default width of 1280px and height of 670px.

When I added the code to make it responsive it is resizing as per the screen size but sometime or on refresh it is not working it loads in 1280px * 670px. How can I get the transform scale value based on the width and height of parent div?

Here is my code:

```
<script> AdobeEdge.loadComposition('Stage', 'EDGE-108722963', { scaleToFit: "width", bScaleToParent: true, centerStage: "none", minW: "280", maxW: "undefined", minH: "280", maxH: "undefined", width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }, { dom: [] }, { dom: [] }); </script>
```

Comment: Can you add the code that you have tried please? https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: <script>

        AdobeEdge.loadComposition('Stage', 'EDGE-108722963', {

            scaleToFit: "width", 
            bScaleToParent: true, 
            centerStage: "none",
            minW: "280",
            maxW: "undefined",
            minH: "280",
            maxH: "undefined",

            width: "100vw",
            height: "100vh"
        }, { dom: [] }, { dom: [] });

    </script>